# Access Mac OS X user Date & Time preferences

Tags: macos, electron

I'm using a calendar app that display a simple Calendar on Mac OS top bar. Currently this app has hardcoded start of the week to Sunday

I would like to be able to know from Electro user's date & type preferences to know what day start they week

I've seen Electron has this method https://electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences#systempreferencesgetuserdefaultkey-type-macos but I'm not sure if from there I can know "Start week day" for the user using the calendar

I would be great to get that info from Electron if possible.

Here is the conversation on Github for reference:
https://github.com/mike-engel/Barnacal/issues/3

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers!
I tried something here: https://github.com/mike-engel/Barnacal/pull/4

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to access the user's first weekday setting by using [systemPreferences.getUserDefault(key, type)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences#systempreferencesgetuserdefaultkey-type-macos).

The relevant `key` is `'AppleFirstWeekday'` and its `type` is `'dictionary'` (object); although quite simple, the data format is a little bit convoluted since it involves getting the numeric value from another key corresponding to the currently used calendar, and also the dictionary will be an empty object if Monday is selected since it is the ISO default...

Anyway, here is some code which works for me from a renderer process, in both macOS Yosemite and El Capitan:

```
const { systemPreferences } = require ('electron').remote;
const weekdays = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ];
let firstWeekday = weekdays[1]; // ISO week starts with Monday (default)
let firstWeekdayDict = systemPreferences.getUserDefault ('AppleFirstWeekday', 'dictionary');
// console.log (firstWeekdayDict);
let weekdayKeys = Object.keys (firstWeekdayDict);
if (weekdayKeys.length > 0)
{
    firstWeekday = weekdays[firstWeekdayDict[weekdayKeys[0]] - 1];
}
console.log (firstWeekday);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution independent of Electron. It also makes use of `AppleFirstWeekday`, but this seems to be only set if the value differs from the locale default.

The solution takes this into account and falls back to the first week day given by the locale default. This functionality is provided by the `weekstart` module (essentially a lookup table). The user locale can be found in `AppleLocale`.

As opposed to the first answer, this solution also returns the correct result in cases where the user didn't override the start of week and the locale defines a first week day different from Monday.

```
const APPLE_WEEKDAY_MAP = {
    1: "Sunday",
    2: "Monday",
    3: "Tuesday",
    4: "Wednesday",
    5: "Thursday",
    6: "Friday",
    7: "Saturday"
}

const { execSync } = require('child_process')

function getUserFirstWeekday() {
    let stdout = execSync('defaults read -g AppleFirstWeekday',
        {stdio: ['inherit', 'pipe', 'ignore']} ).toString()
    let match = /gregorian = (\d)/g.exec(stdout)
    return parseInt(match[1])
}

function getLocaleFirstWeekday() {
    // this returns 0..6 (Sun..Sat)
    const getWeekStartByLocale = require('weekstart').getWeekStartByLocale
    let apple_locale = execSync('defaults read -g AppleLocale').toString()
    return getWeekStartByLocale(apple_locale)
}

function getFirstWeekday() {
    // Use user override if applicable, else fall back to locale default
    try {
        return getUserFirstWeekday()
    }
    catch (e) {
    }

    // Using locale default
    return getLocaleFirstWeekday()+1
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
console.log( getFirstWeekday() )
// prints 5

console.log( APPLE_WEEKDAY_MAP[ getFirstWeekday() ] )
// prints "Thursday"
```

Of course, this shouldn't be used in production as is. For example, there should be (better) error handling, the regex is quite crude, etc. This was tested on Yosemite.

I intentionally worked without the Electron function `systemPreferences.getUserDefault(key, type)` in order to make this answer more universal. Of course, one can easily swap the `exec` calls for the Electron function.